# Iterate through an array with linq which have some null values

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an Array of Questions , some of them are null and some of them have something.
like this :

```
Questions = {null , null , object , null , object}
```

Is the any way to use linq on this array ?

```
Questions.Where(x => x.someValue == OtherValue).ToList();
```

This gives me error

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could filter out the null values first:

```
Questions
    .Where(x => x != null)
    .Where(x => x.someValue == OtherValue)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in a two way instead of a single .Where?? Is there some kind of advantage to it or just readability?

Answer (score 6):

You are getting the error because you try to check for a property on a null object. Try this:

```
Questions.Where(x => (x != null) && (x.someValue == OtherValue)).ToList();
```

Like this, the compiler won't look into the 2nd condition (`x.someValue == OtherValue`) if the first condition is false.

Comment: Or, as @Kote mentioned, C# 6.0 allows you to do this more cleanly usig the null conditional (elvis) operator:
    `Questions.Where(x => x?.someValue == OtherValue).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use C#6 feature [Null conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

```cs
Questions.Where(x => x?.someValue == OtherValue).ToList();
```